# Pass this.state not functioning in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a table that gets data and dynamically displays it,

Passing the "example" the table shows the data without problems,
but when I try to pass:

```
< ResponseTable data={this.state.sprints} ,
```

which is also contains the same structure as example ( Array of objects )
it doesn't work.

```js
var example = [
  {id: 1, sequence: 2, name: "Sprint 2018", state: "CLOSED", linkedPagesCount: 0},
  {id: 2, sequence: 2, name: "Sprint 2018-1", state: "OPEN", linkedPagesCount: 0}
];


class Table extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  fetchData() {
fetch('http://localhost:8000/sprints/23')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => this.setState(myJson));
}

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.sprints)
    console.log(example)
    return(
      <div>
        <ResponseTable data={example} />
      </div>

      );
  }
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> const props = Object.keys(data[0]);

```js
columnsBuilder (data) {        
> 12 |     const props = Object.keys(data[0]);
  13 |     const columns = props.map( (item, index) => ({
  14 |         Header : item,
  15 |         accessor : item,
```

ReactTable ->

```js
export default class ResponseTable extends React.Component {
 
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.columnsBuilder = this.columnsBuilder.bind(this);
    }
    columnsBuilder (data) {        
        const props = Object.keys(data[0]);
        const columns = props.map( (item, index) => ({
            Header : item,
            accessor : item,
            Cell : propss => propss.original[item].length === 0 ? '[]' : propss.original[item].toString(),
        }));
 
        const built = [
            {
                Header : 'Response',
                columns,
            },
        ];        
        return built;
    }
 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactTable
                    data={this.props.data}
                    columns={this.columnsBuilder(this.props.data)}
                    defaultPageSize={10}
                    className="-striped -highlight"
                />
                <br />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: please show full code of ReponseTable not only error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making your API call on `componentDidMount` and sending the data to your component on `render`.

But `render` comes before `componentDidMount` in the [component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

That's why you need to verify if you have the data before passing it down. Like this:

```
...
render() {
    return this.state.sprints ? (
      <div>
        <ResponseTable data={example} />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>
         Loading ...
      </div>
    );
}
```

When you have `this.state.sprints` loaded, your component will update and a re-render will be triggered, showing the table properly.

Comment: Actually,  render comes **before** `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. The general idea with loader is correct but it can be misunderstood by the author.

Comment: Yeah kkk, was a bit distracted.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks @TiagoAlves!

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class ResponseTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) { // Use Props
        super(props); // Use Props
        this.columnsBuilder = this.columnsBuilder.bind(this);
    }
    columnsBuilder () { //Remove data
        const props = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]); //Use Props
        const columns = props.map( (item, index) => ({
            Header : item,
            accessor : item,
            Cell : propss => propss.original[item].length === 0 ? '[]' : propss.original[item].toString(),
        }));

        const built = [
            {
                Header : 'Response',
                columns,
            },
        ];        
        return built;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactTable
                    data={this.props.data}
                    columns={this.columnsBuilder()} // Remove Props
                    defaultPageSize={10}
                    className="-striped -highlight"
                />
                <br />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Please Do check `propss` use have used for `Cell`.

That's it easy!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try set property name:

```
setState({sprints: myJson})
```

as it is missing in this line:

```
.then((myJson) => this.setState(myJson));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to initialize the sprints state with a value if you want to use it in the render method, otherwise it's looking for a key that doesn't exist.
Your constructor could look something like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sprints: {}    
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that until your request is done - your state is empty thus there is no `sprints` property.

You should add it to your constructor in `Table` component.

**Table** component.

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sprints: []
    }
  }
```

Also, you should check if there is items inside of your data in `columnsBuilder` method cause it can also produce an error.

**ResponseTable** component.

```
columnsBuilder (data) {        
    const props = data.length ? Object.keys(data[0]) : data;
    const columns = props.map( (item, index) => ({
        Header : item,
        accessor : item,
        Cell : propss => propss.original[item].length === 0 ? '[]' : propss.original[item].toString(),
    }));

    const built = [
        {
            Header : 'Response',
            columns,
        },
    ];        
    return built;
}
```

Another approach is to check in `render` method if `sprints` is exists in the `state` and use loader as mentioned `Tiago Alves`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the global state with

`.then((myJson) => this.setState(myJson))` basicaly you are overriding `this.state` with new object which is not allowed you always need to only `extend` `this.state` as you are reffering in your code to `this.state.sprints` correct call would be

```
 .then((sprints) => this.setState({sprints))
```

which leverages of using destructuring of objects so it will be same as `{sprints: sprints` React will then merge `this.state` (which is {} at that time from constructor) and merge it with `{sprints: sprints}` which will result to the correct state

```
this.state = {
  sprints: data
}
```

also your code is asynchronous you need to add check inside render it can be easily done with returning null

`if (!this.state.sprints) return null`

which will guard the render method from errors